# SetAction for NSPopUpButton is disabling my popUpButton

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I have created my NSPopUpButton programmatically with the following code

```
[myPopUpButton insertItemWithTitle:@"--Select one--" atIndex:0];
[myPopUpButton addItemsWithTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.One",@"Two",@"Three", nil]];

[myPopUpButton sizeToFit];
[myPopUpButton  setAction:@selector(popUpAction:)];
[fullBrowserView addSubview: myPopUpButton];

//PopUp Action
-(void)popUpAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"popUpAction");
}
```

When I click the popUpButton,menu items of popUpButton are disabled.
When I use interfacebuilder,just it is working fine with the IBAction.

Why this setAction is not working for NSPopUpButton?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you're not setting a *target* object to send the message to. So, in code, add:

```
[myPopUpButton setTarget:self];
```

assuming the `popUpAction:` method is in the same class.

When you're using Interface Builder it's wiring-up the selector action to the target.

From the documentation for this call:

> `- (void)setTarget:(id)anObject`
>
> If anObject is `nil` but the control still has a valid action message assigned, the application follows the responder chain looking for an object that can respond to the message.

In your case, there is no object *responding* to the message.

Answer (score 6):

Even if myPopUpButton has a target and action, you might also need to do add:

```
[myPopUpButton setAutoenablesItems:NO];
```

Otherwise, each time the button is clicked, it can automatically disable all items on its menu.  (I realize this question is old, but posting this solution in case it helps others).